# sequelize.js migration execution sequence

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a several queries I want to do in the same migration. They are related so they have to be executed in the particular order. This is my migration's up method:

```
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
  Promise.all([
    queryInterface.renameColumn(table, 'status', 'status_temp', { transaction }),
    queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      'ALTER TYPE enum_users_status RENAME TO enum_users_status_temp;',
      {
        transaction
      }
    ),
    queryInterface.addColumn(
      table,
      'isActive',
      {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      { transaction }
    ),
    queryInterface.bulkUpdate(
      table,
      {
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        status: 'active'
      },
      { transaction }
    ),
    queryInterface.addColumn(
      table,
      'status',
      {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: STATUS_FREE,
        type: Sequelize.ENUM(STATUS_FREE, STATUS_BUSY, STATUS_DELETED)
      },
      { transaction }
    ),
  ])
),
```

When I'm executing it order is mixing up in a weird way:

```
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): START TRANSACTION;
...
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): ALTER TYPE     enum_users_status RENAME TO enum_users_status_temp;
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): ALTER TABLE "public"."users" ADD COLUMN "isActive" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): UPDATE "users" SET "isActive"=true WHERE "status" = 'active'
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_users_status" AS ENUM('free', 'busy', 'deleted');ALTER TABLE "public"."users" ADD COLUMN "status" "public"."enum_users_status" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'free';
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): ALTER TABLE "users" RENAME COLUMN "status" TO "status_temp";
Executing (591dc838-4659-4de4-b605-54b7c03c527f): ROLLBACK;
```

And I'm getting error because of this:

```
ERROR: column "status" of relation "users" already exists
```

Is there a way to make these queries run in particular order?

UPD:
My expected result is smth like this

```
      START TRANSACTION;
      ALTER TABLE "users" RENAME COLUMN "status" TO "status_temp";
      ALTER TYPE enum_users_status RENAME TO enum_users_status_temp;
      ALTER TABLE "public"."users" ADD COLUMN "isNew" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true;
      UPDATE "users" SET "isNew"=false WHERE "status_temp" = 'active';
      CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_users_status" AS ENUM('free', 'busy', 'deleted');
      ALTER TABLE "public"."users" ADD COLUMN "status" "public"."enum_users_status" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'free';
      UPDATE "users" SET "status"='busy' WHERE "isFree" = false;
      UPDATE "users" SET "status"='deleted' WHERE "status_temp" = 'deleted';
      ALTER TABLE "public"."users" DROP COLUMN "isFree";
      ALTER TABLE "public"."users" DROP COLUMN "status_temp";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're using `Promise.all` which execute promises in parallel. There is no guarantee that your promises will be executed in order they defined. So you need to use `.then` method to execute your workflow consequentially.

```
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
  queryInterface.renameColumn(table, 'status', 'status_temp', { transaction })
    .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      'ALTER TYPE enum_users_status RENAME TO enum_users_status_temp;',
      {
        transaction
      }
    ))
    .then(...);
),
```

Comment: Is it possible to just simply make them query in one transaction in the sequence that i wrote them without these ugly then() repetitions?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with then()?  

Use async/await if you don't like then()

Comment: you wont be able to use transaction like in your example

Comment: Why? No difference, it just an order of execution

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene pointed out, your problem is that you are calling all your migrations with `Promise.all`. I will highly recommend to do individual migrations files. This way you have a better structure of your project and easier to understand to new developers.

command to create a migration:

```
sequelize migration:generate --name [name-of-your-migration]
```

to execute all the migrations on creation order and those that where not run already:

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure if it's a good idea. I want to put in one file all queries that are logically related. This example is out of date but I need to:
1. create 1 more field
2. delete one existing field 
3. change status field
PS: data in all these fields should be migrated from previous versions of fields
so that's why i put it all together
+ because of migrations are all in the same folder i think it's not a good idea to make  extras

Comment: @ArtsemStalavitski you can keep the array of promises, but instead use a `for of` loop to execute each one in the order that were added to the array (`for-of` accepts `await` calls). Because `Promise.all` executes all the promises simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using bluebirdjs [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) function with `{concurrency: 1}` option as below:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
...

up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return Promise.map([
            queryInterface.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0'),
            queryInterface.addColumn(
                'table1',
                'column1',
                {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    after: 'id',
                    defaultValue: 0
                }),
            queryInterface.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1'),
            queryInterface.addColumn(
                'table2',
                'column2',
                {
                    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                    after: 'column3',
                    defaultValue: 0
                })
        ],
        (promise) => promise,
        {concurrency: 1}
    );
}
```

Note: You can set `concurrency` option to `n` in order to execute `n` promises concurrently